Calculating daily sum as a separate column for each day
I think this should be a relatively simple question, I'm just not sure how to do it. I have two dataframes. The first dataframe includes positions for each day and each day includes multiple positions.
DF1:



Date
InstrumentID
DollarAmt




6/17/2024
ABC
1237710.88


6/17/2024
DEF
3785016.6


6/17/2024
GHI
8073892.08


6/17/2024
JKL
1239084.56


6/17/2024
MNO
1981981.96


6/17/2024
PQR
741914.0625


6/17/2024
STU
482246.0938


6/17/2024
VWX
747128.9063


6/17/2024
YZ
6231908.57


6/18/2024
ABC
1223553.78


6/18/2024
DEF
3742955.56


6/18/2024
GHI
8055188.67


6/18/2024
JKL
1228704.36


6/18/2024
MNO
1961685.05


6/18/2024
PQR
742089.8438


6/18/2024
STU
482353.5156


6/18/2024
VWX
747246.0938


6/18/2024
YZ
6231908.57


6/18/2024
ACD
94344.13



I also have another dataframe, where I've separately calculated daily totals of the DollarAmt column from the first dataframe.
DF2:



Date
Total




6/17/2024
24520883.71


6/18/2024
24510029.57



What I'm looking for is the following, where a separate column in the first dataframe is created and displays the daily totals from the second dataframe, as below. I'm still new to python so the best way I could come up with to do this was to create a separate dataframe with the totals and then merge. But that end output isn't exactly what I'm looking for. The desired result is below:
Desired Output:



Date
InstrumentID
DollarAmt
Total




6/17/2024
ABC
1237710.88
24520883.71


6/17/2024
DEF
3785016.6
24520883.71


6/17/2024
GHI
8073892.08
24520883.71


6/17/2024
JKL
1239084.56
24520883.71


6/17/2024
MNO
1981981.96
24520883.71


6/17/2024
PQR
741914.0625
24520883.71


6/17/2024
STU
482246.0938
24520883.71


6/17/2024
VWX
747128.9063
24520883.71


6/17/2024
YZ
6231908.57
24520883.71


6/18/2024
ABC
1223553.78
24510029.57


6/18/2024
DEF
3742955.56
24510029.57


6/18/2024
GHI
8055188.67
24510029.57


6/18/2024
JKL
1228704.36
24510029.57


6/18/2024
MNO
1961685.05
24510029.57


6/18/2024
PQR
742089.8438
24510029.57


6/18/2024
STU
482353.5156
24510029.57


6/18/2024
VWX
747246.0938
24510029.57


6/18/2024
YZ
6231908.57
24510029.57


6/18/2024
ACD
94344.13
24510029.57



Thanks very much for any and all help, it's appreciated.

even you are not sure how to solve it, please try to attempt and include part of a solution to get any helpful feedback...

You can merge df1 and df2 with how='left':
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how="left")

But you don't need to calculate the sums separately on df2. You can do it directly on df1, using groupby on 'Date', then transform with 'sum':
df1["Total"] = df1.groupby("Date")["DollarAmt"].transform("sum")

Both will output (using pd.set_option("display.float_format", "{:.2f}".format) to prevent scientific notation):
         Date InstrumentID  DollarAmt       Total
0   6/17/2024          ABC 1237710.88 24520883.71
1   6/17/2024          DEF 3785016.60 24520883.71
2   6/17/2024          GHI 8073892.08 24520883.71
3   6/17/2024          JKL 1239084.56 24520883.71
4   6/17/2024          MNO 1981981.96 24520883.71
5   6/17/2024          PQR  741914.06 24520883.71
6   6/17/2024          STU  482246.09 24520883.71
7   6/17/2024          VWX  747128.91 24520883.71
8   6/17/2024           YZ 6231908.57 24520883.71
9   6/18/2024          ABC 1223553.78 24510029.57
10  6/18/2024          DEF 3742955.56 24510029.57
11  6/18/2024          GHI 8055188.67 24510029.57
12  6/18/2024          JKL 1228704.36 24510029.57
13  6/18/2024          MNO 1961685.05 24510029.57
14  6/18/2024          PQR  742089.84 24510029.57
15  6/18/2024          STU  482353.52 24510029.57
16  6/18/2024          VWX  747246.09 24510029.57
17  6/18/2024           YZ 6231908.57 24510029.57
18  6/18/2024          ACD   94344.13 24510029.57


Ah, ok thanks. I think I was trying to go in a different direction but this is much better. Much appreciated!
